# Powershell: File properties - Bytes to Mb

Tags: powershell, properties-file

Currently have the following script that outputs some file data to a report.  The file length is in bytes though and wondering how I can convert that to MB before outputting to the array.

```
$arr = @()
gci C:\stuff -recurse | ? {$_.PSIsContainer -eq $False} | % {
   $obj = New-Object PSObject
   $obj | Add-Member NoteProperty Directory $_.DirectoryName
   $obj | Add-Member NoteProperty Name $_.Name
   $obj | Add-Member NoteProperty Length $_.Length
   $obj | Add-Member NoteProperty created $_.creationtime
   $obj | Add-Member NoteProperty Access $_.LastAccessTime
   $obj | Add-Member NoteProperty LastWritten $_.LastWriteTime
   $obj | Add-Member NoteProperty Extension $_.Extension
   $obj | Add-Member NoteProperty Owner ((Get-ACL $_.FullName).Owner)
   $arr += $obj
}
$arr | Export-CSV -notypeinformation "c:\files.csv"
```

Comment: Already tried a typical conversion, it doesnt like it in the context of the add-member                                                                                           Add-Member : The SecondValue parameter is not necessary for a member of type "NoteProperty", and should not be specified. 
Do not specify the SecondValue parameter when you add members of this type.
At line:6 char:10
+   $obj | Add-Member NoteProperty Length $_.Length/1mb
+          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Add-Member], InvalidOperationException

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When converting into MB, just put brackets around it:

```
 $obj | Add-Member NoteProperty Length ($_.Length/1MB)
```

or maybe more useful:

```
 $obj | Add-Member NoteProperty MB ("{0:N3}" -f ($_.Length/1MB))
```

to only show the first three digits after the point.

Comment: Add-Member : The SecondValue parameter is not necessary for a member of type "NoteProperty", and should not be specified. 
Do not specify the SecondValue parameter when you add members of this type.
At line:6 char:10
+   $obj | Add-Member NoteProperty File Size (($_.Length/1MB))

Comment: tried double parens there, but even when i do single, same error.

Comment: What version of PowerShell are you using? This works fine on Vs.4